# Proof of cardinality of Q

Tags: logic

There is a nice and easy way to see that Q is countable, you take the injective mapping from N to Q defined in an obvious way($a$ to $\frac{a}{1}$) and injective mapping from $Q^+$(positive rationals) to N (take $\frac{a}{b}$ to $a^b$) and $Q$ and $Q^+$ are obviously bijective, so there certainly is a way to directly construct a function one-to-one from Q to N.

What I need is the proof of the theorem I used here, so:

> Theorem: If the sets A and B are such that there are injective functions from A to B and from B to A, then there is a bijection between A and B

For finite sets this is clear, and not a theorem at all(if there is injection from set A to set B, and both are finite there must hold |A| $\leq$ |B| hence the statement) but what about infinite ones? I think that going from injective $f:A \to B$ and injective $g:B \to A$ and trying to construct $h:A \to B$ using those two is a waste of time, at least I do not know how to do this, and I have no other ideas.

I will appreciate any help, advice, complete proofs, hints, or links to books in logic where this is proved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your map from $Q^+$ to $N$ is not injective.  For example, both 3/4 and 9/2 get mapped to 81.  But there are other functions that would work.  For example, you could map $a/b$ to $2^a (2b + 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem (or Cantor-Bernstein, or Schröder-Bernstein, or sometimes Cantor-Schröder). At a glance, it looks like Wikipedia's proof is pretty good.

As a matter of fact, construction a bijection $h$ from injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ is exactly what you do. The basic thought is to bounce back and forth by alternating $f$ and $g$, and their inverses, so you have a (potentially bi-infinite) sequence $\cdots \to g^{-1}(f^{-1}(x)) \to f^{-1}(x) \to x \to g(x) \to f(g(x)) \to \cdots$, and argue that (basically) either $f$ or $g$ can be used as a bijection between the members of $A$ and the members of $B$ in this sequence.

I'll leave the rest of the details for you to work out or look up - Googling Cantor-Bernstein will give you plenty of proofs.